# Windows7 API, where to find it

Tags: c++, windows

Where can I find documentation on W7 API? I've found what's new in Win7 API but full documentation seems to be "unfindable".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Windows API Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff818516.aspx) on the [Microsoft developer site](http://msdn.com)

And [here's the overview / programming guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663300.aspx).

It includes the new stuff, like "Direct2D" and "Windows Ribbon", along with all the old (but improved) stuff, like "Files and I/O" and the old unchanged stuff like "List Boxes".

[image]
[image]

Comment: @Alan: I mostly use google also, because I usually know the name of the function (or a related one).  But for an index, I started at the homepage.  It's only two clicks: Library -> Desktop - Windows Client - API Reference.

Comment: TWO CLICKS? UX FAIL. Jk. nice job.

Answer (score 0):

The [Windows 7 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=3138) download comes with Documentation. It's not as ideal as having an online reference, but it should unblock you.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately I've cap on my internet allowance and I'm at the end of the limit, so cannot really download it right now. Is there any online source?

Comment: @smallB: while I've not performed an exhaustive search, from what I did do, I came to a similar conclusion as yours: the documentation isn't online (at least not easily accessible).

Comment: @smallB: Yes, click the first link in my answer.